# How to configure Bundler to use a local gem dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt, rubygems, bundler

The Qt library is broken on OSX 12 (Sierra), which is one of the dependancies for the gem `capybara-webkit`. So at the moment `bundle install` will fail for most folks if `capybara-webkit` is in the Gemfile.

There is [a workaround for this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macos-sierra-1012), which involves installing Qt manually and then using the local version to install the gem...

```
$ PATH=~/Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin:$PATH gem install capybara-webkit
```

I want to configure bundler to *always* use this local copy of Qt so I don't have to remember to do this in every gemset. Is this possible? I've looked at the [Bundler config](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html) documentation and didn't quite see what I was looking for.

Ideally, I'd love to find a solution that used a portable config file that I could pass around to my team, rather than a sequence of commands they all have to run.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a [local git repo](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html#LOCAL-GIT-REPOS) for bundler.

> Bundler also allows you to work against a git repository locally instead of using the remote version. This can be achieved by setting up a local override:
>
> `bundle config local.GEM_NAME /path/to/local/git/repository`
>
> For example, in order to use a local Rack repository, a developer could call:
>
> `bundle config local.rack ~/Work/git/rack`
>
> Now instead of checking out the remote git repository, the local override will be used. Similar to a path source, every time the local git repository change, changes will be automatically picked up by Bundler. This means a commit in the local git repo will update the revision in the Gemfile.lock to the local git repo revision. This requires the same attention as git submodules. Before pushing to the remote, you need to ensure the local override was pushed, otherwise you may point to a commit that only exists in your local machine.

If your current local copy of Qt is not in a git repo you can simply clone the main repo and push your change to it locally on your computer.